# Relacion de muchos a muchos en laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Estoy realizando la asignacion de Docentes - Grados, es decir tengo un modelo Docente y un modelo Grado y su relacion es de muchos a muchos por lo que a la hora de hacer la migracion de crea una tabla pivote docente_grado. Segun entiendo laravel no usa un modelo en la tabla pivote. El asunto es que para realizar dicha asignacion tengo que mostrar en el index.blade.php la tabla pivote(registros de la misma) y la verdad no se como hacerlo, es decir no se como referenciarla. De igual modo necesito guardar en la tabla pivote las asignaciones.

Modelo Docente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo Grado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Migracion de tabla Docente.

```
class CreateDocenteTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('docentes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('nip')->unique();
        $table->string('nombres', 100);
        $table->string('apellidos', 100);
        $table->string('dui', 12)->unique();
        $table->string('nit', 20)->unique();
        $table->string('especialidad', 50);

        $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('docentes');
    }
}
```

### Migracion de tabla Grado.

```
class CreateGradoTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('grados', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('idturno')->unsigned();
        $table->string('nombre', 60);
         $table->foreign('idturno')->references('id')->on('turnos')->onDelete('cascade');
       $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('docente_grado', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('iddocente')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('idgrado')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('iddocente')->references('id')->on('docentes')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('idgrado')->references('id')->on('grados')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
            });

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('docente_grado');
        Schema::dropIfExists('grados');
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código de las migraciones y los modelos respectivos.

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo se usa Many To Many, aquí está la documentación
[Many To Many Laravel](http://Many%20To%20Many%20Laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes un error al definir las claves de la relación, lo tienes igual en los dos modelos, en el modelo Grado lo tienes que cambiar de orden, es decir primero la clave de grado y después la de docente.